# How I can configure TFS 2013/2015 MTM Alerts?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, mtm

We are using Microsoft Test Manager to test the applications, how we can configure the emails alerts for MTM activities (Test case, test suite status ...)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you still have questions about this?

Answer (score 2):

MTM is a kind of client for TFS. It doesn't have any email alerts setting. All email alerts are configured in TFS.

To get an email notification when Test case status changes:

1. In TFS admin console, configure a SMTP server for Email Alert setting.
2. Follow [this link](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) to create a personal or team alert. Add a Alert filter: `State Changes`.
   [image]